# Cross operations between two datafarames

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe, outer-join, quantitative-finance

Two fairly big dataframes `df1` and `df2` have many columns with float values. **For same index and column name in `df1` and `df2`**, create two new dataframes `simple_ret_df` and `log_ret_df` with following operations respectively:

1. `(1 - df1 / df2)`.  Lets say this new dataframe is `simple_ret_df`
2. `ln(df1 / df2)`.  Lets say this new dataframe is `log_ret_df`

If any of the entry in dataframe `df1` or `df2` is missing \ `nan`\ `0` then corresponding entry in computed dataframes should be `nan`. Sample dataframes `df1` and `df2` can be generated as given below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(10*(2+np.random.randn(500, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(10*(2+np.random.randn(500, 3)), columns=list('CDA'))
df1.drop(df1.index[[1, 4, 284, 354, 498]], inplace=True)
df2.drop(df2.index[[0, 98, 159]], inplace=True)
df1.loc[2, 'B'] = np.nan
df1.loc[5, 'C'] = np.nan
df1.loc[3, 'A'] = np.nan
df2.loc[5, 'C'] = np.nan
df2.loc[1, 'D'] = np.nan
df2.loc[2, 'A'] = np.nan
```

Sample input dataframes `df1` and `df2` are as follows:

```
df1.head()
      A     B     C 
0  14.0  31.3  35.5
2  24.2   NaN  27.6
3   NaN  13.1  16.0
5  28.2   8.8   NaN
6  17.7  18.0   7.9
df2.head()
      C     D     A
1  15.1   NaN  27.0
2  20.9  29.4   NaN
3  27.8  29.7  22.9
4  19.0  13.5  21.0
5   NaN  21.4  12.0
```

Corresponding sample output dataframes `simple_ret_df` and `log_ret_df` are as follows:

```
simple_ret_df.head(6)
          A    B        C     D
0       NaN  NaN      NaN   NaN
1       NaN  NaN      NaN   NaN
2       NaN  NaN  -0.3206   NaN
3       NaN  NaN   0.4245   NaN
4       NaN  NaN      NaN   NaN
5   -0.4750  NaN      NaN   NaN

log_ret_df.head(6)
          A    B        C     D
0       NaN  NaN      NaN   NaN
1       NaN  NaN      NaN   NaN
2       NaN  NaN   0.2781   NaN
3       NaN  NaN  -0.5524   NaN
4       NaN  NaN      NaN   NaN
5    0.3887  NaN      NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the output? Also, the operations are between particular set of columns or across all columns.

Comment: Also, when should the operations execute? When is (1 - df1 / df2) used and when is ln(df1 / df2) used?

Comment: @Jorge apologies for the delay and confusion. I have clarified the text and added sample input and corresponding output as well.

Comment: does my answer below solved your question?

Comment: @Jorge No not really.

Comment: I am not following your logic. In your example both input dataframes have a value in colum A row 0, yet your outputs are nan in that cell. That is not in agreement with your question. Can you explain that?

Comment: added the option to check for zero as well. Not sure if that is what was missing. Let me know

Comment: @Jorge `df1` starts from row 1 while `df2` starts from row 0 and then `df2` doesn't have row 1. Hence in output both row 0 and row 1 are both `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of answer my questions in the comments. Here is a solution for you. I made it on Python3 and your tag is python 2, so you may need to change some of the code.

Here is the whole code with from the beginning.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(10*(2+np.random.randn(500, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(10*(2+np.random.randn(500, 3)), columns=list('CDA'))
df1.drop(df1.index[[1, 4, 284, 354, 498]], inplace=True)
df2.drop(df2.index[[0, 98, 159]], inplace=True)
df1.loc[2, 'B'] = np.nan
df1.loc[5, 'C'] = np.nan
df1.loc[3, 'A'] = np.nan
df2.loc[5, 'C'] = np.nan
df2.loc[1, 'D'] = np.nan
df2.loc[2, 'A'] = np.nan

df1.head(10)

    A   B   C
0   20.438695   18.114421   20.445370
2   12.789906   NaN 3.988319
3   NaN 11.026463   9.421921
5   19.919580   7.462012    NaN
6   21.290647   23.952295   -10.354758
7   8.447708    14.710224   25.499204
8   16.603850   24.862611   20.354342
9   6.088232    15.066117   22.906491
10  19.621493   15.877428   15.149765
11  2.052592    9.031476    19.531663

df2.head(10)

C   D   A
1   15.159127   NaN 29.432163
2   23.449304   8.393440    NaN
3   6.057011    32.881258   21.033391
4   31.162671   4.128745    23.264304
5   NaN 32.796018   11.171984
6   32.019817   14.603303   33.106655
7   17.566806   26.804403   12.421421
8   30.121336   46.520462   41.934098
9   13.498463   30.170049   24.221281
10  19.554489   28.238385   26.284620


    # Merge the dataframes
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, right_index = True, left_index = True, how = 'outer')
# Create dataframes for each formula
final_df1 = pd.DataFrame(index = merged_df.index) # for this (1 - df1 / df2)
final_df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = merged_df.index) # for this ln(df1 / df2)
for column in merged_df.columns:
    # Get initial letter from the column names
    i = column[0]
    # filter only the columns that start with the same letter
    df_test = merged_df[merged_df.columns[merged_df.columns.str.startswith(i)]]
    #If only one column, add that to the dataframes
    if df_test.shape[1] == 1:
        final_df1 = final_df1.merge(df_test, right_index = True, left_index = True, how = 'outer')
        final_df2 = final_df2.merge(df_test, right_index = True, left_index = True, how = 'outer')
    #If two columns do the calculations
    else:
        final_df1.loc[:,i] = np.where((df_test[df_test.columns[0]].isnull())|(df_test[df_test.columns[1]].isnull()), 
        np.nan,  (1- df_test[df_test.columns[0]]) / df_test[df_test.columns[1]])
        final_df2.loc[:,i] = np.where((df_test[df_test.columns[0]].isnull())|(df_test[df_test.columns[1]].isnull()), 
        np.nan,  np.log(df_test[df_test.columns[0]] / df_test[df_test.columns[1]]))

#Adjust the names of the columns
final_df1.columns = final_df1.columns.str[0]
final_df2.columns = final_df2.columns.str[0]

print(final_df1.head(10), final_df2.head(10))
```

Giving this:

```
    simple_ret_df.head(6) 

           A          B         C          D
0       NaN  18.114421       NaN        NaN
1       NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN
2       NaN        NaN -0.127437   8.393440
3       NaN  11.026463 -1.390442  32.881258
4       NaN        NaN       NaN   4.128745
5 -1.693484   7.462012       NaN  32.796018 

 log_ret_df.head(6) 
           A          B         C          D
0       NaN  18.114421       NaN        NaN
1       NaN        NaN       NaN        NaN
2       NaN        NaN -1.771471   8.393440
3       NaN  11.026463  0.441823  32.881258
4       NaN        NaN       NaN   4.128745
5  0.578294   7.462012       NaN  32.796018
```

Comment: for the reasons, I explained above this is not the correct output.

Comment: I placed my whole script. Columns A and C are the only common columns, therefore are the only ones that change. is this correct? Then in df1 and df2 mimic yours, the difference is some of the values, and the resulting df are doing what you ask for. is it?

Comment: `(df1 + df2).head(6)` would help sort out the `nan` thing, i.e., how I am getting `nan` at some places but not all.

Answer (score 0):

```
simple_ret_df = df1.combine(df2, lambda s1, s2: 1-s1/s2)
log_ret_df = df1.combine(df2, lambda s1, s2: np.log(s1/s2))
```